# Prove $\frac{i}{(i+z)\sqrt{\frac{i-z}{i+z}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove
$$\frac{i}{(i+z)\sqrt{\frac{i-z}{i+z}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}},\, z\in\mathbb{C}.$$
$i+z$ cannot be put under the square root, because it is not true that, in general, $(ab)^r=a^r b^r$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. I'm stuck here.

**Edit:** $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal branch of the square root. Also, *the equality isn't true for every* $z\in\mathbb{C}$, as Maxim points out.

Comment: Could you provide a counter example to $(ab)^r=a^rb^r$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @ABCD $1=((-1)(-1))^{\frac{1}{2}}\ne (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=-1$

Comment: Hmmm...I see....

Comment: We have
$$\frac {i - z} {i + z} < 0 \Leftrightarrow z \in D, \\
z^2 + 1 < 0 \Leftrightarrow z \in D,$$
where $D = \{i t: t < -1 \lor t > 1 \}$. The equality holds on $\mathbb C \setminus \overline D$ (since there are only two analytic branches of $1/\sqrt {z^2 + 1}$ on $\mathbb C \setminus \overline D$, it suffices to check a single point). It remains to check $z \in D$. The equality holds only on the ray in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @Maxim Are you sure? The equality in the question is correct for $z=-1-i$, which is not on the ray in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @Mr Pink, you misunderstood Maxim. Equality holds for $-1-i$ since it is in $\mathbb C\setminus \overline D$. Maxim's last sentence only applies to points in $D$.

Comment: @Ennar Alright, what equality are we talking about in the first place?

Comment: @Mr Pink, the one you wrote in your question, obviously. What Maxim wrote tells you that your equality holds everywhere except on $\{i\}\cup \{ it \mid t \leq - 1\}$.

Comment: @Ennar I see. I didn't realize that he meant the last sentence only for $D$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* square both sides.

The equality should be interpreted as

> for $z\ne\pm i$, if $\sqrt{(i-z)/(i+z)}$ is a determination of the square root, then $\dfrac{i}{(i+z)\sqrt{(i-z)/(i+z)}}$ is a determination of $1/\sqrt{z^2+1}$.

This can be ascertained by squaring: $w$ is a determination of $\sqrt{z}$ if and only if $w^2=z$.

Now, the square of the left-hand side is
$$
\frac{-1}{(i+z)^2\cfrac{i-z}{i+z}}=\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}
$$

Comment: What does 'determination' mean in this context?

Comment: @MrPink There is no “canonical” choice for the square root: for each nonzero complex number, you have two “determinations” of them.

Comment: @MrPink The “proofs” that $-1=1$ usually rely on $\sqrt{z_1}\sqrt{z_2}=\sqrt{z_1z_2}$, which is true under the interpretation “given determinations of $\sqrt{z_1}$ and $\sqrt{z_2}$, then $\sqrt{z_1}\sqrt{z_2}$ is a determination of $\sqrt{z_1z_2}$”; however, you can't tell *what* determination. For instance, $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$ *is* a determination of $\sqrt{1}$. Indeed, $i^2=-1$, which *is* a determination of $\sqrt{1}$ (in the complex numbers).

Comment: If I start with a false identity, $-1=1$, then squaring both sides gives $1=1$. I don't know if I understand this correctly, but I think you're doing the "backwards" process: $(-1)^2=1\implies -1=\pm \sqrt{1}$ which, of course, can be correct (based on the determination). But what if I *start* with the false identity? I thought that this was exactly what made the proof by squaring both sides invalid.

Comment: @MrPink I firmly believe that $\sqrt{z}$ should ***never*** be used in connection with algebraic operations, unless $\sqrt{z}$ is precisely defined with a branch cut, because you need to extend the meaning of $=$ as I described. One could also interpret $\sqrt{z_1}\sqrt{z_2}$ and $\sqrt{z_1z_2}$ as two-element sets, which are equal. But doing algebra with square roots can be very dangerous.

Comment: It means that the identity I started with $(-1=1)$ is either correct or correct up to a sign. How can I check which case it is? It should be possible, I think, as $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},\, f(z)=z^2$ is perfectly defined...

Comment: @MrPink Just don't overthink on this.

Comment: I think I finally got it: let $f(z)=\frac{i}{(i+z)\sqrt{\frac{i-z}{i+z}}}$ and $g(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}$ where $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal branch of the square root. We have $f^2 (z)=(-f(z))^2=g(z)^2$, so $-f(z)$ is the problem here. But since the "un-squared" sides can either be correct or correct up to a sign, we can check that $-f(0)=-1\ne g(0)=1$. Therefore $f(z)=g(z)$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: There should have been "sides can either be *equal*"...

Comment: @MrPink What do you mean by “principal branch”? Is the argument in $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: $\sqrt{a+bi}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Arg}(a+bi)}$ where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge 0$ and $-\pi \lt\operatorname{Arg}(a+bi)\le \pi$.

Comment: I meant $\sqrt{a+bi}=\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Arg}(a+bi)}$ where $\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}\ge 0$ and $-\pi\lt\operatorname{Arg}(a+bi)\le \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that $\sqrt{\frac ab}$ might not be equal to $\frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ and the classic case is that $1 = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)}$ but $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = i*i = -1$.

But it's okay.  There is not *one* square root of any number but two and so $\sqrt{1}$ is *not* written in stone by God to be equal to $1$ and only $1$ and never equal to $-1$.  It's an arbitrary choice we make.  And though if $\sqrt{ab}$ need not be equal to $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ if we make arbitrary rules about how we choose which one is *the* square root, it is true that if $w^2 = a$ and $v^2 = b$ and $(vw)^2 = ab$. So each of the square roots of $ab$ is the one of the two possible products of the square roots of $a$ and be.

That is to say:  the square root***S*** of $1$ are $1$ and $-1$. And the square root***S*** of $-1$ are $i$ and $-i$.  So so if we think $1 = (-1)^2$ then stating $\sqrt{1} = -1$ is okay as *one* of the square roots and $-1 = \sqrt{(-1)*(-1)} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt {-1} =\begin{cases}i*i \\(-i)*(-i)\end{cases}$ are fine.  And thinking of $1=1^2$ then stating $\sqrt{1} =1$ is okay as one of the square roots and $1 = \sqrt{1}*\sqrt{1} = 1*1$ is dandy.

Okays suppose $w^2 = i+z$ so $\sqrt {i+z} = \pm w$ and we choose $w$.  And suppose $v^2 = i-z$ so $\sqrt{i-z} = \pm v$.  Let's choose $v$.  That would mean $(\frac vw)^2 = \frac {i-z}{i+z}$ and $\sqrt{\frac {i-z}{i+z}}= \pm\frac vw$. Let's choose $\frac vw$ for consistancy.

Now we have $\frac i{(i+z)\sqrt{\frac {i-z}{i+z}}} =$

$\frac i{w^2 \frac {\pm v}{w}} = \frac i{\pm wv}$

Now $(wv)^2 = w^2v^2 = (i-z)(i+z)=z^2 + 1$ so $\sqrt{z^2 + 1} = \pm wv$.  lets choose $wv$ for consistancy and we are done.

Comment: That's a thorough explanation. Thanks. I should have mentioned that, in my question, $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal branch of the square root.